# How do I run my react front-end and express back-end together?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I'm attempting to build a simple react/node/express app from scratch (not using the create-react-app). I've built out a simple back end to pass some data to the front end but am having a hard time figuring out how the two communicate. How can I run the front-end and back-end together and view the front-end with the data passed into it?

I'd like to do this all in one command. Do I have to use a tool like webpack to bundle everything together into one runnable package?

My repo can be found here, it is the react-and-express branch that I've linked to. Any help is much appreciated! Currently I'm running the app by starting index.js but that is only the backend, how do I run my front-end App.js and get the two to communicate?

https://github.com/int-a/contacts-application/tree/react-and-express

Comment: It's a very broad question, but for development you most likely want something like Webpack and the webpack-dev-server to compile your React app, and proxy e.g. `/api` requests to your Express server. In production you could have the Express server serve all your compiled static assets.

Comment: It's better if you keep both application (backend and frontend) separate, that the all idea of use an SPA in the frontend. With docker you can make the deploy really ease and keep out the backend the responsibility of the frontend

Answer (score 0):

You can use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run two node commands at the same time (1 for front-end and 1 for back-end). And then use the [proxy configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) in webpack dev server to alias the calls to the backend port number for the same machine.